# Is there a way to get a tree of all events on a web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, dom-events

Context: I'm tasked with building a visualizer that crawls our application and builds a tree of all possible user flows. I'm currently trying to use a list of all events on the page as tree nodes; trigger those events; and recursively continue this process. Obviously, there are a lot of problems with this approach. Specifically there are many event handlers that don't appear until certain actions are completed (ie. an input is non-empty, or an element is hovered over to reveal a hidden menu), and I have no idea how to access these events.

So, I'm asking to see if anyone has come across this problem before / know of any similar library out there. If not, any suggestions for ways to do this effectively would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not even sure what this means. Events aren't hierarchical. All of this is dynamic, I'm not sure how much you can determine from a static analysis.

Comment: Is this a homework task? Did the class give any guidance about how you're supposed to approach this?

Comment: dynamic tree logging is possible. for static one try AST

Comment: We're tasked with building a web crawler to do a dynamic analysis, not static.